# Axis2 File Upload by chunk

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, java-io

I'm trying to upload file using Axis2 web service by 1024 chunk size.

My server side looks like this:

```
public void appendChunk(int count, byte[] buffer){
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
     try {
         File destinationFile = new File("c:\\file1.exe");
        fos = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile,true);
        fos.write(buffer,0, count);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        try {
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

my client side looks like this:

```
static int CHUNK_SIZE =1024;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ServiceException {
    FileUploadService strub = new FileUploadServiceLocator();
    FileUploadServicePortType a = strub.getFileUploadServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    File file = new File("C:\\install.exe");
    int count;
    try {
         fis =  new FileInputStream(file);
        while((count = fis.read(buffer, 0, CHUNK_SIZE)) >0 )
        {
            a.appendChunk(count, buffer);
        }   
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        finally{
            fis.close();
        }
}
```

After it the file size is incorrect and if origina file size is 500 Kb, the original size varies between 200 and 400k.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:** I looked at log4j file in Tomcat

```
Nov 17, 2010 2:08:31 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint createWorkerThread
INFO: Maximum number of threads (200) created for connector with address null and port 80
```

It looks like all requests to the web server are done Asynchronously and and I also getting IO exception that the file is used by another process.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're using webservices for this? This will have a very high overhead since your data will get converted to base64 before getting embedded in xml, each chunk will probably also use a new TCP connection. Why not use a simple http post request to a servlet instead?

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately there is a reason, I have third party client which uploads binary data that way :( and I will have to write Web Service which will be compliant with this client. I understand that I'll have performance issue with all SOAP headers, but to be honest I don't care.

Answer (score 1):

try to add `fos.flush();` before your `fos.close();` in your server implementation.

Change

```
while((count = fis.read(buffer, 0, CHUNK_SIZE)) >0 )
```

for

```
while((count = fis.read(buffer, 0, CHUNK_SIZE)) != -1 )
```